# How to clear ajax response before another call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have this Ajax call that populate the table with data. However, when I make the same call again, it loads both new and old data. How can I clear the old data before loading new data?

```
$(function() {
$('#subject_search_btn').click(function() {
    var student_id = $('#search').val();
    var year = $('#year').val();
    var term = $('#term').val();
    var classs = $('#formclass').val();

    $.ajax({
        "url": "/search_student_results",
        "data": {"studentid":student_id, "year":year, "term":term, "formclass":classs},
        "type": "get",
        "dataType": "json",
        "success": function(data) {
            if (data.length == 0){
                alert(year+' '+'Term'+' '+term+' '+'Results not found');
            }
            else
            var trHTML = '';
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                trHTML += '<tr>' +
                    '<td>' + item.subject.name + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.score + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.position + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.remark + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
            });
            $('#subject_tbody').append(trHTML);
        },
        "error": function() {
            alert(year+' '+'Term'+' '+term+' '+'Results not found');
        }
    });
});
});
```

I have unsuccessfully tried

```
var subject_score = $('.subjectscore').filter(function() {
                        subject_score.empty();
```

or:

```
            var subject_score = $('.subjectscore').filter(function() {
                subject_score.parent().parent().remove();
```

Please help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

It will remove the content of the table, add your cleardata and after that your ajax received data.

```
$(function() {
    $('#subject_search_btn').click(function() {
        var student_id = $('#search').val();
        var year = $('#year').val();
        var term = $('#term').val();
        var classs = $('#formclass').val();

        $.ajax({
            "url": "/search_student_results",
            "data": {"studentid":student_id, "year":year, "term":term, "formclass":classs},
            "type": "get",
            "dataType": "json",
            "success": function(data) {
                if (data.length == 0){
                    alert(year+' '+'Term'+' '+term+' '+'Results not found');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#subject_tbody').empty();
                    var clearHTML = '<tr> <td class="cleardata"></td> <td class="cleardata"></td> <td class="cleardata"></td> <td class="cleardata"></td> </tr>';
                    var trHTML = '';
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        trHTML += '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + item.subject.name + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + item.score + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + item.position + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + item.remark + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>';
                    });
                    $('#subject_tbody').append(clearHTML);
                    $('#subject_tbody').append(trHTML);
                }
            },
            "error": function() {
                alert(year+' '+'Term'+' '+term+' '+'Results not found');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Wouter Bouwman, That is a td class.         <tbody id="subject_tbody">
        <tr>
          <td class="cleardata"></td>
          <td class="cleardata"></td>
          <td class="cleardata"></td>
          <td class="cleardata"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>

Comment: I've updated my answer. Is this what you want?
It will remove the content first. Then it will add the cleardata back and after that the ajax received student data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly how I want it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .html(html) function instead:

```
$('#subject_tbody').html(trHTML);
```

Or clear the contents first before append:

```
$('#subject_tbody').html('').append(trHTML);
```

Comment: Folkert, Your suggestion is not loading any data. I guess its clearing after the data is loaded. I tried putting it after $('#subject_search_btn').click(function() { and after $.each(data, function (i, item) {. Both are giving me the same result.

Comment: You should replace `$('#subject_tbody').append(trHTML);` with one of the two examples in my answer. Oh, and I think you are missing curly brackets after the 'else' in your ajax success function.

Comment: You can also insert `$('#subject_tbody').html('<tr><td colspan="4">Loading...</td></tr>');` as your first line in the click handler to show a loading message...

Answer (score 0):

the clearconsole(); function can help

```
$(document).on("click", ".class, function(e) { 
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/ajax/getData.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){                

        },error: function(){

    });
    clearconsole();
 });
```

this worked when you use load(); with a page that has and ajax code. the ajax seems to be executed every time you load(); the page without refreshing the browser